# Url link does not show the thumbnail picture on facebook link

Tags: facebook, dns, thumbnails, forwarding

I use domain name forwarding with my other website for example:

> > http://www.xxx.net forward to http://119.1.1.1:8181/Test

When I type "http://www.xxx.net" on facebook wall, the image thumbnail does not show on facebook. I suppose that when I use domain name forwarding, the html will create frameset tag  over the forwarded ip destination.

I want to know how to solve that problem because I want to show image in http://119.1.1.1:8181/Test.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but does your page contain the `og:image` meta tag as described in the [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already putted og:image between head tag. But I want to get query string to identify image location such as http://www.xxx.com/content.php?id=1. 

And I use javascript to get id number from query string and also create metag tag using Open Graph in javascript code. It does not really work.